# UI for NativeScript RadCharts use labels with decimals by default

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I’ve been doing some experimenting with [UI for NativeScript](http://www.telerik.com/nativescript-ui)’s charts—which are awesome, by the way—but I’m running into an odd problem I can’t seem to figure out.

On Android, the control suite loves to render all of my numeric labels with a decimal point—aka “15.0” rather than “15”. In my case (and probably in most cases) this behavior is undesirable, and I’m trying to come up with a way around this, but I’m not seeing anything in the API documentation.

To give a concrete example of what I mean, here’s the world’s simplest example that shows this behavior in action.

```
<!-- main-page.xml -->
<Page 
  xmlns:chart="nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/chart"
  loaded="pageLoaded">
  <StackLayout>
    <chart:RadCartesianChart height="500">
      <chart:RadCartesianChart.series>
        <chart:LineSeries
          items="{{ data }}"
          categoryProperty="key"
          valueProperty="value">
          <chart:LineSeries.horizontalAxis>
            <chart:CategoricalAxis />
          </chart:LineSeries.horizontalAxis>
          <chart:LineSeries.verticalAxis>
            <chart:LinearAxis />
          </chart:LineSeries.verticalAxis>
        </chart:LineSeries>
      </chart:RadCartesianChart.series>
    </chart:RadCartesianChart>
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

---

```
// main-page.js
var frameModule = require("ui/frame");
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;

var pageData = new Observable();
pageData.data = [
  { key: "One", value: 10 },
  { key: "Two", value: 20 }
];

exports.pageLoaded = function(args) {
  var page = args.object;
  page.bindingContext = pageData;
};
```

With this code, on iOS you end up with a vertical axis with keys like “0, 4, 8, 12”, and on Android that same axis has keys like “0.00, “5.00” & “10.00”.

How can I get the decimal points to go away on Android?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `labelFormat` property of the [LinearAxis](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/linearaxis.html#labelformat) and set it to the desired format. For example to make it display the float values without any trailing zeros you can use the "%.0f" format:

```
<chart:LineSeries.verticalAxis>
     <chart:LinearAxis android:labelFormat="%.0f"/>
</chart:LineSeries.verticalAxis>
```

It is worth mentioning that you can use the dedicated [NativeScript UI forums](http://www.telerik.com/forums/nativescript-ui) where you can find answers to many questions regarding all of the components of the nativescript-telerik-ui-pro plugin. You can also take advantage of the dedicated paid support ticketing system which provides answers no longer than 24 hours, more information can be found [here](http://www.telerik.com/nativescript-ui).